# Does driver.findElement(By.className) locate a class that has multiple class names?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've got this HTML:

```
<class = "abc pqr"></class>
```

So if I do a `driver.findElement(By.className("abc")`, will WebDriver actually find the class in the `DOM` structure?

What I want to know is, does the `By.className` work if we provide just a substring of the class?

Comment: Do you want to find all element which have same class name?

Comment: First: why not simply try it out?

Comment: @HelpingHands I want to locate the element uniquely. So will a unique substring locate it?

Comment: I suggest you to use XPATH  to find that element. do no try with class if class name is like you mentioned.

Comment: do NOT USE XPATH, use CSS instead.

Comment: @SkorpEN ir really doesn't matter if they use xpath or css.   The performance difference is negligible nowadays, and xpath is actually more widely compatible than using css selectors is.  I have ran across websites that don't work with selenium css selectors, but xpath works every time.

Comment: OP: can you please edit/improve this question to use typical HTML/CSS structures, e.g. `<a class="abc pqr" href="....">Lorem ipsum ...</a>` instead of `<class ...>` which means nothing. I tried to fix this in an edit, but it was rejected "This edit was intended to address the author".

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes! Either `By.className("abc")` or `By.className("pqr")` is perfectly fine in **this** case.

Note that this is **not** using a *sub-string*. In your element `<class = "abc pqr"/>`, this a space-separated list of classes!

Answer (score 2):

If you still need the answer - yes, it will. It will not wok in case if you will try to search it like `By.classname("abc pqr")` it won't.

If you want to search by part of class use css selector. Imagine you have

```
<a class="superclass secondaryclass">
```

Then you can find it with:

`By.cssSelector("//a[class*=super]")`

as `*=` is search by substring (not strict one).

If you still want to search by xpath and substring, then you can do some tricks like:

`//a[substring(@class, string-length(@class) - 5) = 'super']`

Or try to use `a[contains(@class, 'super')]`

There are too many ways to do it :)

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:  no.   You will have to use one of the below methods for selecting an element based on multiple class names.

```
driver.find(By.cssSelector(".abc.pqr"));
```

or

```
driver.find(By.xpath("//*[@class='abc pqr']"));
```